# Dr Racket total sum with recursion

Tags: racket

I am new to `dr racket`, am trying to write one function that returns true if

1. list contains 3 elements
2. If the sum of the sub-list of three elements equals the sum of the remainder of the 
   list, assuming the list contains four or more elements.

No use of built in functions.

```racket
(define myfunction(lambda (sub subSum count restListSum myList)
 (cond
  ((null? myList) (cond
     ((= 0 subSum) #f)
     ((= 0 count) #f)
     ((= 3(count myList) #t)
     ((= subSum restListSum) #t)
     ((myfunction subSum(+ sub)) (car myList)) (+ count 1) (cdr myList)) #t)
     ((myfunction sub subsum count(cdr myList)) #t)
     ((myfunction car myList) subsume sub count (cdr myList)) #t)
     ((and (not (= subSum 0)) (myfunction 1 (car myList) (+ count 1) (cdd myList))) #t)
        (else #f))))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't pass a syntax check.  Rather than try to decode it for you, let me offer you this simple definition of a 'count' function, which returns the number of things in the list.  This might help you take a step forward in reworking your own first attempt.  Keep trying!  You might define two or three helper functions for yourself as a starting point.  You also need a function that takes a single parameter (the list) as a starting point.

```
(define (count theList)  
    (cond
      ((null? theList) 0)
      (else (+ 1 (count(cdr theList))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to stick to your initial idea and would suggest the following:

```
(define (myfunc lst)

  (define (inner-function lst count sum1-3 sum4-x)  
    (if (empty? lst)
        (cond
          ((< count 3) 'error)
          ((= count 3) #t)
          (else (= sum1-3 sum4-x)))
        (inner-function 
         (cdr lst) 
         (+ count 1) 
         (if (< count 3) 
             (+ sum1-3 (car lst)) 
             sum1-3)
         (if (< count 3) 
             sum4-x 
             (+ sum4-x (car lst))))))

  (inner-function lst 0 0 0))
```